# $var being held even when page is refreshed, how / why?

Tags: php, variables, post

Ive made a really simple form that posts to itself, then there is a script that gets the `$_POST` data and saves it to a variable as below.

Whats odd is that if i run this and then refresh the page, the $posted variable still holds the data.

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="data">
   <button type="submit">Send Data</button>
</form> 


if (!empty($_POST)) {
  $posted = trim($_POST['data']);
}

echo $posted;
```

Comment: You're probably resubmitting the form each time

Comment: Also, make sure you're not loading from cache.  In Firefox you can use `CTRL + F5` to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking at a page which has already had form data submitted to it, and you hit the refresh button, "most" browsers will tell you that you're about to resubmit the form data again. For instance, here's the Chrome dialog which does this:

[image: Chrome form resubmission]

If you want to reload the page **without** resubmitting the form data, I believe you need to click in the address bar and hit enter to re-load the page from scratch (this definitely works, but there may be cooler/easier ways to achieve this that I'm unaware of).

Answer (score 1):

When you reload a page, it will send the same question again, with the same POST data, so it will come out with the same answer.

Comment: How could i prevent this from happening ?

Comment: Do a 3xx redirect after processing the post data.

Comment: Dont refresh your webpage. If you click on the URL in your browser, and press ENTER, it should clear. "Refresh" means "I want you to get exactly the same page again"